# React Bootstrap adjust width of text inputs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a row something like shown below:

[image]

Below is my React component code for "Row":

```
  /*
   * The render method of this component
   */
  render() {
      return (
        <form className="form-inline">
            <FormGroup>
              <InputGroup>
                <InputGroup.Addon>
                <input name="cb" type="checkbox" value={this.state.cb} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </InputGroup.Addon>
                <div>
                <FormControl name="remarks" type="text" value={this.state.remarks} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                <FormControl name="amount" type="text" value={this.state.amount} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
              </InputGroup>
            </FormGroup>
        </form>
      );
  }
}
```

The problem is I want to increase the **width** of the "input text type" fields, however may be being not a CSS champ, I am not able to increase it. Asking here after quite some time of Googling and frustration :)

Anyone to help? Thanks

Comment: Guys, any help? Should be simple for css folks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And yes I got the solution:

As described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline):

> **May require custom widths:**
>   Inputs and selects have width: 100%; applied
>   by default in Bootstrap. Within inline forms, we reset that to width:
>   auto; so multiple controls can reside on the same line. Depending on
>   your layout, additional custom widths may be required.

So, one has to give custom width to all elements to adjust their widths and hence I used following `CSS`:

```
.form-inline {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group {
  width: 90%;
}

.input-group {
  width: 90% !important;
}

.form-control {
  width: 50% !important;
}

span.input-group-addon {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

to achieve good looking width for my table:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add `className='w-50'` to the `FormControl` Component

```
      <FormControl
        className="w-50"
        name="remarks"
        type="text"
        value={this.state.remarks}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      />
      <FormControl
        className="w-50"
        name="amount"
        type="text"
        value={this.state.amount}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      />
```

Or you can simply add bootstrap grid to the page

refer the below link for react bootstrap grid

[React Bootstrap Grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/)